# Pre signed aws s3 url slowness

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to secure s3 resources and i have created temporary credential using sts service in the same region where bucket exist . I am using these credential to create a pre signed url which will expire after one hour. These url are images and will be shown on a mobile app . But after implementation, we are experiencing slowness in the response from s3 . Does anyone experienced same behaviour ?

This is how i am generating pre signed url

```java
try {
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(getTemporaryAwsCredentials());

    // Generate the pre signed URL.
    LOGGER.info("Generating pre-signed URL for " + unsignedUrl);
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, fileName).withMethod(HttpMethod.GET);

    URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

    LOGGER.info("Pre-Signed URL: " + url.toString());
    return url.toString();

} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Error while generating pre signed url ", e);
}
```

```java
private AWSCredentials getTemporaryAwsCredentials() {

    AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient sts_client = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(getCredentials());
    sts_client.setEndpoint("sts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com");

    GetSessionTokenRequest session_token_request = new GetSessionTokenRequest();
    session_token_request.setDurationSeconds(43200);

    GetSessionTokenResult session_token_result = sts_client.getSessionToken(session_token_request);

    Credentials session_creds = session_token_result.getCredentials();

    BasicSessionCredentials sessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
        session_creds.getAccessKeyId(),
        session_creds.getSecretAccessKey(),
        session_creds.getSessionToken());

    return sessionCredentials;
}
```

Comment: I see multiple problems here.  You shouldn't be instantiating an AmazonS3Client each time you want to generate a pre-signed URL -- you should be doing it once, and reusing it.  You also shouldn't be calling STS each time.  Worse, though, there seems to be no purpose for using `getSessionToken()`.  You already have credentials for the same principal in your app, which you are fetching with `getCredentials()` and that's a problem, too -- it appears your app has embedded credentials, which is a big security risk that is not mediated by unnecessarily calling STS.  This seems very insecure.

Comment: Add some timestamps to your log messages and you should find that the slowdown is unrelated to S3.

Comment: Michael thanks for identifying issues in the code . This is not production ready code . We are just trying it out . Idea is to generate temporary credentials valid for 12 hours and reuse those credentials and regenerate the credential before it expires .

Comment: but i can see heavy degrade in the performance if we use pre signed urls on the mobile app .

Comment: Yes, this code would be extremely slow, as written, but the slowness is caused by the way you are *generating* the pre-signed URLs -- not the fact that you are *using* pre-signed URLs.  As I mentioned, log some timestamps and you should see what I am saying.

Comment: You said *"slowness in the response from S3*" but it occurs to me, now, that you may not realize the fact that when your code reaches `return url.toString();`, **no interaction with S3 has yet occurred** ... so all slowness to that point has been the overhead of instantiating the `AmazonS3Client`, including fetching the temporary credentials from STS.  You need to have already finished doing all of these things *before* you actually start creating signed URLs.  Actually generating signed URLs is done locally, with no S3 interaction -- signed URLs are created by the SDK without talking to S3.

Comment: Michael once the mobile client receives the signed image urls , images are loading very slowly as compare to unsigned image urls .

Comment: some times it take 4 - 5 second to load the images